# Avoiding `setTimeout` 'hack' to ensure state is in sync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I wrote a small todo app using React, in which the user can add and remove items to their list.

As a bonus feature, the list is saved to `localStorage` as it's mutated by the user, and used on the initial mount of the component.

In both the `addTodo` and `removeTodo` methods, the pattern is this:

1. Set the new state by adding or removing an item of `this.state.todos`
2. Copy the state to `localStorage`

For example, here is the `removeTodo` method:

```
removeTodo(indexOfItemToRemove) {
    const todosCopy = this.state.todos.slice();

    todosCopy.splice(indexOfItemToRemove, 1);

    this.setState({
        todos: todosCopy
    });

    this.updateLocalStorageWithState();
}
```

Here is what I am currently doing to save `this.state.todos` to `localStorage`

```
updateLocalStorageWithState() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('localStorageTodos', JSON.stringify(this.state.todos));
    }, 1);
}
```

I found that without using `setTimeout`, the `localStorage` was always 1 step behind, using what the user might perceive as an outdated version of the list.

This feels like a hack. How can I incorporate a way of doing the same thing without having to use a `setTimeout` hack?

Comment: What about `this.setState()` ? Is there something `async`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState()` is not necessarily executed synchronuosly. This causes the behavior you are experiencing:

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.
>
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to `setState` and calls may be batched for performance gains.

[Source](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

---

Luckily, `setState()` takes a second parameter, which is a callback that is called when the state update has been completed. You can use that to synchronize your local storage entry:

```
this.setState({
    todos: todosCopy
}, () => {
    localStorage.setItem('localStorageTodos', JSON.stringify(this.state.todos));
});
```

---

Alternatively, why not set the local storage entry directly instead of reading from `state` first?

```
this.setState({
    todos: todosCopy
});

localStorage.setItem('localStorageTodos', JSON.stringify(todosCopy));
```